# Making a slightly more efficient function structure

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, kivy

I have a bunch of lights I'm trying to control. Rather than have each button state change call a unique function I want to try and have a multipurpose function as thats what functions are for (as far as I understand).

Button calling function:

```
    ToggleButton:
        id: KitchenSpot1Toggle
        text: "Kitchen Spot 1"
        on_press: root.changeKS1(1)
```

The function:

```
def changeKS1(self,change):
        if change==1 and b.get_light(1, 'on'):
            self.KitchenSpot1(False)
        else:
            self.KitchenSpot1(True)
```

That function then calls this function to physically change the state of the light using a 3rd part library.

```
    def KitchenSpot1(self,state):
        lights[0].name
        lights[0].on = state
```

The reason I passed "1" inside of the function is because it didn't like having nothing passed in it (I don't know why it didn't like it). If you hadn't already guessed it, I am new at this. I have a bit of a cpp micro controller background but I'm trying to get my head around python and PC based programming. I'm looking for a bit of advice on how best I can condense this and make it as efficient as possible. I may not know much about python, but, I know I shouldn't be typing practically the same thing out 30 times.

Thanks in advance to anyone that can share some of their wisdom.

Its with noting I am using kivy with python to generate the button.

Full main.py code:

```
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
import kivy
from kivy.uix.togglebutton import ToggleButton
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.app import App
kivy.require('1.10.0')
from phue import Bridge
import nest
b = Bridge('xx.xxx.xxx.xxx')
b.connect()
b.get_api()
lights = b.lights

class Controller(GridLayout):
    state = StringProperty('down')

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Controller, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1.0 / 60.0)

    def KitchenSpot1(self,state):
        lights[0].name
        lights[0].on = state

    def changeKS1(self,change):
        if change==1 and b.get_light(1, 'on'):
            self.KitchenSpot1(False)
        else:
            self.KitchenSpot1(True)


    def KitchenSpot2(self,state):
        lights[1].name
        lights[1].on = state

    def KitchenSpot3(self,state):
        lights[2].name
        lights[2].on = state

    def OfficeSpot1(self,state):
        lights[3].name
        lights[3].on = state

    def OfficeSpot2(self,state):
        lights[4].name
        lights[4].on = state

    def OfficeSpot3(self,state):
        lights[5].name
        lights[5].on = state

    def OfficeSpot4(self,state):
        lights[6].name
        lights[6].on = state

    def JuliaBedside(self,state):
        lights[7].name
        lights[7].on = state

    def JohnBedside(self,state):
        lights[8].name
        lights[8].on = state





    def update(self, dt):
        if b.get_light(1, 'on'):
            self.state = 'down'
         else:
            self.state = 'normal'


class ActionApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Controller()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    myApp = ActionApp()
    myApp.run()
```

Full action.kv code

```
<Controller>:
    cols: 4
    rows: 3
    spacing: 10
    state: "normal"                                      

    ToggleButton:
        id: KitchenSpot1Toggle
        text: "Kitchen Spot 1"
        on_press: root.changeKS1(1)

        #on_release: root.KitchenSpot1(False)
        #state1 = app.update.h
        state: root.state


    ToggleButton:
        text: "Kitchen Spot 2"

    Button:
        text: "Kitchen Spot 3"

    Button:
        text: "Kitchen Spot 4"

    Button:
        text: "Office Spot 1"

    Button:
        text: "Office Spot 2"

    Button:
        text: "Office Spot 3"

    Button:
        text: "Office Spot 4"
```

Update:
Python program:

```
    def lightcontrol(self,lightnumber):
        if b.get_light(1, 'on'):
            lights[lightnumber].name
            lights[lightnumber].on (False)
            #self.KitchenSpot1(False)
        else:
            lights[lightnumber].name
            lights[lightnumber].on (True)
            #self.KitchenSpot1(True)
```

Kivy button:

```
    ToggleButton:
        id: KitchenSpot1Toggle
        text: "Kitchen Spot 1"
        on_press: root.lightcontrol(0)
```

Comment: Can please provide your complete code?

Comment: That is the full code added. The button is in the action.kv code and it calls a function in the main.py code.

Comment: According to [the source code](https://github.com/studioimaginaire/phue/blob/master/phue.py#L840), the `get_light()` method needs a light_id. If you leave it to `None` (default value), it seems to return the result of a request depending on the user name... don't know more about how this works.

Answer (score 1):

Have each button call the *same* function but with a different parameter.

```
# Add the a number parameter here based on what you've
def KitchenSpot(self,state, light_index):
    lights[light_index].name
    lights[light_index].on = state
```

Then in the KV file,

```
Button:
    text: "Kitchen Spot 3"
    on_press: root.KitchenSpot(state, light_index = 3)

Button:
    text: "Kitchen Spot 4"
    on_press: root.KitchenSpot(state, light_index = 4)
```

You only have to create the function one, with each button passing in the relevant light_index number.

Comment: I don't see how that will work because there is a bit missed. The button press calls a function to switch the light to its alternative state, that function then calls another function to cause the change. Button press >>> changeKS1 >>> KitchenSpot1.

Answer (score 0):

Neither knowing kivy nor phue I've tried to reduce the problem to your code redundancy by abstracting the definition of your methods (and also the creation of your `action.kv` file).

So I hope this what you are looking for: First, I would define all the relevant data of the buttons in a global variable, like:

```
BUTTONS = [
    {'id': 0, 'methodname': 'KitchenSpot1', 'text': 'Kitchen Spot 1'},
    {'id': 1, 'methodname': 'KitchenSpot2', 'text': 'Kitchen Spot 2'},
    ...
]
```

Then define your Controller-class with all unique methods just like you did (`__init__` and `update` in your case; however I don't see what update should do, I just left it be):

```
class Controller(GridLayout):
    state = StringProperty('down')
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Controller, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1.0 / 60.0)
    def update(self, dt):
        if b.get_light(1, 'on'):
            self.state = 'down'
         else:
            self.state = 'normal'

# this iteratively creates your button-individual methods
for button_dict in BUTTONS:        
    def func(self, state):
        lights[button_dict['id']].name   # whatever this might do just adressing the name attribute. Is it a python-property on lights that does some action?
        lights[button_dict['id']].on = state

    def func_change(self, change):
        if change == True and b.get_light(button_dict['id'], 'on'):
            getattr(self, button_dict['methodname'])(False)
        else:
            getattr(self, button_dict['methodname'])(True)

    # create .KitchenSpot1, .KitchenSpot2, ...
    setattr(Controller, button_dict['methodname'], func)
    # create .changeKitchenSpot1, .changeKitchenSpot2, ...
    setattr(Controller, "change{}".format(button_dict['methodname']), func_change)
```

The instantiated Controller will have bound methods named accordingly to all methodnames and change-methodnames.

Finally you can create your `action.kv` file dynamically

```
actionkv_toggle_button = """    
    ToggleButton:
        id: {methodname}Toggle
        text: "{text}"
        on_press: root.change{methodname}(1)

        #on_release: root.{methodname}(False)
        #state1 = app.update.h
        state: root.state
"""

actionkv_str = """
<Controller>:
    cols: 4
    rows: 3
    spacing: 10
    state: "normal"

{buttons}
""".format(
    buttons="".join([
        actionkv_toggle_button.format(
            methodname=button_dict['methodname'],
            text=button_dict['text']
        ) for button_dict in BUTTONS
    ])
)
```

this gives the output

```
<Controller>:
    cols: 4
    rows: 3
    spacing: 10
    state: "normal"


    ToggleButton:
        id: KitchenSpot1Toggle
        text: "Kitchen Spot 1"
        on_press: root.changeKitchenSpot1(1)

        #on_release: root.KitchenSpot1(False)
        #state1 = app.update.h
        state: root.state

    ToggleButton:
        id: KitchenSpot2Toggle
        text: "Kitchen Spot 2"
        on_press: root.changeKitchenSpot2(1)

        #on_release: root.KitchenSpot2(False)
        #state1 = app.update.h
        state: root.state
```

Save it to a file

```
with open('action.kv', 'w') as f:
    f.write(actionkv_str)
```

Helpful links:

[Dynamically attaching methods to a class](http://block.arch.ethz.ch/blog/2016/07/adding-methods-to-python-classes/)

[String formatting in python](https://pyformat.info/#named_placeholders)

[List comprehension](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk)

Comment: Thanks for doing that. I vaguely follow what you have done and I am sure that this is the most condensed form of my code, but I have to admit I am slight lost as my python knowledge is weak just now. This project is a learning exercise for me as much as anything else so although I could run your code and have it work I don't think I'm learning anything by doing that. I have a basic grasp of functions and it is those functions I am looking to condense for now (baby steps I know).

Comment: I understand. Maybe it aids your understanding if you dissect my code from "inner to outer brackets" and debug it with print statements, so you can observe what it does. I'm sure if you'll get through it, you will learn a valuable (advanced) coding paradigm - and learn to strictly follow the DRY-principle ;)

Comment: I will give that a shot. I took a summer course in python at my university which now looks like child's play in comparison. I will battle through you code and see what I can pick up.

Comment: I've added two links that might help understanding the critical parts.

Comment: So in light of your advice I have tried to make a reusable function called lightcontrol. when I run it the GUI loads up fine but when I clock the kitchen spot 1 button I get the error      "lights[lightnumber].on (True)
 TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable". Why would I be getting this error? when I had a boolean change inside the previous function it didn't throw this error up. I put the updated code above.

Comment: ignore my last comment I mixed up functions and objects.